# Turn 2d array of tiles into the smallest possible array of rectangles that cover all of the tiles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making a game where the player can place tiles anywhere, and they are solid, having a ton of small squares for collision at once would probably cause lag on shitty pcs so im trying to optimize them into as few rectangles as possible.
I have no idea if this is possible at all but it would be nice, rectangles CAN overlap but that would be nice to have avoided if it doesnt save rectangles. (eg.

```
.....
.###.
.#...
.#...
.....
```

should turn into `x: 1, y: 1, w: 3, h: 1` and `x: 1, y: 2, w: 1, h: 2` or the other way around, but not overlapping because it doesnt save anything)

it would be really cool to have a way to add/remove a tile to this and have it still be mostly optimal without recalculating everything but thats probably not happening

Comment: There are multiple ways you could approach this but if you want to avoid iterating over the full array when a change is made, one way would be to check the adjacent array cells whenever a tile is added or removed and recalculate from there. Each cell covered by a rectangle would need to have a reference to that rectangle, and any rectangle affected by a removed tile would need to be recalculated. 
Depending on how much detail you want to go to consolidating the rectangles in the most efficient way, it could be pretty complex. Not impossible someone will know of an existing solution I guess.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.